# lein 2.3.4 checkout dependencies - can't detect submodule classpath

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have 2 `lein` projects as below at the same level,

```
nepleaks-front/project.clj
nepleaks-webservice/project.clj
```

`nepleaks-front` submodules `nepleaks-webservice` which I did with following commands,

```
cd nepleaks-front
mkdir checkouts
cd checkouts
ls -s ../nepleaks-webservice webservice.checkout
```

When I do `lein ring server` on `nepleaks-front`, I get following `classpath` error on dependency of `nepleaks-webservice` not visible from `nepleaks-front`. At least submodule (`nepleaks-webservice`) seems invoked.

```
$ lein ring server
WARNING: get already refers to: #'clojure.core/get in namespace: nepleaks.views.leak, being replaced by: #'clj-http.client/get
WARNING: get already refers to: #'clojure.core/get in namespace: nepleaks.views.dashboard, being replaced by: #'clj-http.client/get
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clj_yaml/core__init.class or clj_yaml/core.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at nepleaks_engine.conf.config$eval4279$loading__4910__auto____4280.invoke(config.clj:1)
    at nepleaks_engine.conf.config$eval4279.invoke(config.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
    at nepleaks_webservice.services.esService$eval3976$loading__4910__auto____3977.invoke(esService.clj:5)
    at nepleaks_webservice.services.esService$eval3976.invoke(esService.clj:5)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at nepleaks.views.dashboard$eval3970$loading__4910__auto____3971.invoke(dashboard.clj:6)
    at nepleaks.views.dashboard$eval3970.invoke(dashboard.clj:6)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
    at nepleaks.handler$eval1694$loading__4910__auto____1695.invoke(handler.clj:6)
    at nepleaks.handler$eval1694.invoke(handler.clj:6)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init3014223470004988473.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:299)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Subprocess failed
```

`[clj-yaml "0.4.0"]` of `nepleaks-webservice` is not visible to `nepleaks-front` as I checked with `lein classpath | grep 'yaml'`.

`nepleaks-webservice` alone works fine with command `lein run -m nepleaks-webservice.controller`.

Maybe I'm wrong with `:dependencies` part in project.clj of `nepleaks-front`, which I havent' set. Putting `[nepleaks-webservice "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]` searches in remote repository though.

**Full code [on github](https://github.com/prayagupd/nepleaks/tree/nepleaks-checkout)**

```
git clone --branch nepleaks-checkout https://github.com/prayagupd/nepleaks.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I did `lein install` on `nepleaks-front` before attempting to run `nepleaks-webservice`, I'm also symlinking using the project name in `checkouts`:

```
ls -s ../nepleaks-webservice webservice.checkout
```

Finally I uncommented the dependency from `nepleaks-front`to `nepleaks-webservice`. Thats what I normally do with checkouts and they usually work for me (not using sub modules in this approach, I have never used them so far); perhaps I've passed that problem as I see a different exception regarding hiccup templates:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: escape-html already refers to: #'hiccup.core/escape-html in namespace: hiccup.page
at clojure.lang.Namespace.warnOrFailOnReplace(Namespace.java:88)
at clojure.lang.Namespace.reference(Namespace.java:110)
at clojure.lang.Namespace.refer(Namespace.java:168)
at clojure.core$refer.doInvoke(core.clj:3850)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5394)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at hiccup.page$eval59$loading__4910__auto____60.invoke(page.clj:1)
at hiccup.page$eval59.invoke(page.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
at ring.middleware.stacktrace$eval53$loading__4910__auto____54.invoke(stacktrace.clj:1)
at ring.middleware.stacktrace$eval53.invoke(stacktrace.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
at ring.server.standalone$eval13$loading__4910__auto____14.invoke(standalone.clj:1)
at ring.server.standalone$eval13.invoke(standalone.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at ring.server.leiningen$eval7$loading__4910__auto____8.invoke(leiningen.clj:1)
at ring.server.leiningen$eval7.invoke(leiningen.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at user$eval3.invoke(form-init4550004760096621936.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:299)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

This one looks more like a library dependencies problem but I haven't further investigated yet. Does the `lein install` seem to solve the checkout dependency problem for you?

Comment: `lein install` on `nepleaks-engine` seems to fix the issue. I think  you mix the names to run `lein install` on. But the above hiccup issue is because of storm dependency (which doesn't seem to have solution other than separating it as a standalone project - https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/issues/86#issuecomment-40467187). Thx for your quick answer.

Comment: That didn't fix my issue. Every dependency seems clean.